# How to make the addition of two complex numbers identical to another addition

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers

Let's say we have the following :

$$\quad x_1=Ae^{j\phi_1}+Be^{j\phi_2} $$
 $$\quad x_2=Ce^{j\phi_1}+De^{j\phi_2} $$

---

where:
 $\phi_1\ , \phi_2$ 
,$\,A\,$,$\,B\,$,$\,C\,$,$\,D\,$ are different and **unknown**
$A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{R}$

All what we know:
$A+B\,$ is **known**
$C+D\,$ is **known**

Also what's common between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is that they have the same $\phi_1$ and the same $\phi_2$
Another thing it's easy to have other candidates $x_3\,,$ $x_4\,,$ $x_5\,...$ with the same form above.

---

My **question** is :

Is there any way to make $x_2=x_1$  ? Using the fact that we know $C+D$ in $x_2$ and $A+B$ in $x_1$  ?

Or at least, can we **suppress** $C$ and $D$ in $x_2$ by using the value $C+D$ that we know ? where by **suppress** I mean to make their value as small as possible.

---

**Motivation**
Of course if we only have one complex number, the problem will be easy, like:

if:   $$\quad x_1=Ae^{j\phi_1} $$
 $$\quad x_2=Ce^{j\phi_1} $$

1) Divide $x_2$ by $C$ $$\frac{x_2}{C}=\frac{Ce^{j\phi}}{C} =e^{j\phi} $$
2) Multiply the result by $A$ :  $$A*e^{j\phi} = Ae^{j\phi} = x_1$$

** Note that in this case we Know $A$ and $C$ but above we only know the sum $A+B$ and $C+D$

Comment: Are $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{R}$ or $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Then for $x_1=x_2$, there must be $A+B=C+D$, no matter $ϕ_1=ϕ_2$ or $ϕ_1\neq ϕ_2$.

Comment: Thank you but the question is not when $x_1=x_2$ ? It is what kind of operations (multiplication, division,etc) can be applied to $x_2$ to make it equal to $x_1$ ?
$A+B\neq C+D $ in general, and I want to adjust $x_2$ so that $A+B = C+D $ $\; i.e \; x_2=x_1\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

Idea: you have a linear system with unknowns $A,B,C,D$ (see also the comment by Alex Francisco):
$$A + e^{j(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}B = C + e^{j(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}D,$$
$$A + B = k;$$
$$C + D = k.$$
Apply the general theory of linear systems...

Comment: But how ? We have more unknowns than equations.

Comment: @MOADELMAJDOB, you can apply the general theory in this case. The only "problem" is that if the solution exists not will be unique.